# Tcl command to find latest created folder in a directory

Tags: find, tcl

i have a folder where there are subfolder with dates
example : Parent/2020-11-09_15.47.36
Parent/2020-11-10_16.52.02 and so on.
now I want to find out which is the latest date folder inside Parent folder using tcl command.

output should be : 2020-11-10_16.52.02

Comment: Do you want to inspect the date this folder was created, or may the result be based on the folder's name only.

Comment: i want the latest date folder created inside Parent folder.

Comment: find /Parent/20* -type d -prune -exec ls -d {} \; | tail -1            i have used this in shell to get the latest folder, but want the same in tcl

Answer (score 1):

You picked a sensible datetime format that sorts the same lexically as chronologically.

In Tcl you would do

```
cd Parent
set subdirs [glob -type d *]
set last [lindex [lsort $subdirs] end]
```

If you have other subdirectories in there that would interfere with the sorting, and you want to filter them out, you can do:

```
set subdirs [lmap dir [glob -type d *] {
  if {![regexp {^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}$} $dir]} then continue
  set dir
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lindex [ lsort -decreasing [ glob -type d Parent/* ] ] 0
```